# Simple PHP and jquery contact form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, contacts

I was looking for a simple contact form in jQuery and I found out this one on Google

http://code.google.com/p/gunnertech/source/browse/trunk/public/javascripts/contact.js?r=3

the problem is that it is missing the PHP part. Here is the part where the script handle the message and pass it to the PHP file:

```
function send(a, d){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: a,
    data: d,
    success: handle
  });
}
```

I don't know what this "a" and "d" means. Do you know what do I need to do in order to make this jquery form work and simply send the content to a specified email address? Thanks.

EDIT: thanks to everyone. Now I understand what the two letters means. The problem is that I don't know what to write in the PHP file to send the data to my email! This is the HTML part:

```
<form method="post" action="/" id="contact"> 
    <div> 
        <label for="contact-text" class="js-placeholder placeholder">
            <span>Type your name, email, and message here.</span>
        </label> 
        <textarea aria-required="true" required="" rows="1" cols="70" id="contact-text" name="contact_text" style="height: 15px; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
        </textarea> 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="contactsend" id="contactsend">
</form>
```

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: `a` is the URL that the data will be sent to, and `d` is the data that you are sending. You should read the manual for [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose 'a' would be the form's 'action' attribute. And 'd' the forms 'data', meaning the form's fields concatenated into one string (which you'd then need to parse in your php script).

EDIT: Could you also post the part where the 'send' function is called?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. You mean this one:

`<input id="contactsend" type="submit" value="Send" name="contactsend">` ? 

The problem is that I don't know what to write in the PHP file to make this works =\

Comment: That's not the one I meant. What I meant is that you need to call 'send(argument1, argument2)' somewhere to actually send the form data.

Answer (score 0):

a is your contact form handler `(ex: contact.php)` and d is the data you want to pass to it, for ex: `{name: 'Joe', age: 27}`

Answer (score 0):

The function is looking for the action file (where the PHP is). So whatever you set `<form action="">` to jQuery will send to it. "d" is the data your contact form is collecting sent serialized to your action file.

You can create a simple php file to handle the data that works the same way a traditional PHP send mail would work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your posted code:

```
//note that d get the data from your contact form
var a = 'your_contact_page.php';
var d = {name: 'your_name_from_contact', subject: 'subject_from_conatc_form'}

function send(a, d){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: a,
    data: d,
    success: handle
  });
}
```

and `handle` is also a function that will produce you the response

Comment: Really thanks for your help. The problem is that I don't know what to write in the PHP file to make the contact form work and send this data to an email.

Comment: if you will providing your code with html then i will help you to do that

Comment: Thanks, this is the html part:

`<form method="post" action="/" id="contact">
<div>
<label for="contact-text" class="js-placeholder placeholder"><span>Type your name, email, and message here.</span></label>
<textarea aria-required="true" required="" rows="1" cols="70" id="contact-text" name="contact_text" style="height: 15px; overflow: hidden; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="contactsend" id="contactsend">
</form>`